# why @character is missing while i split string using comma(,) in andorid?

Tags: android, json, string, split

> 1.here i want same string as on xml format but while i store into array it missed @ from the string and added space

`<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">7633,abcd@123</string>`

```
loginDetailsArray = loginDetails.split(",");
        intPersonID = loginDetailsArray[0];
        strPassword = loginDetailsArray[1];
```

> 2. separeted using comma

`resultstring=abcd 123`//@ is missing

Comment: post your exact code.

Comment: I wonder what's in the String `loginDetails`.

Comment: loginDetails = WebServiceFPassword.invokeWebMethod(
     editTextUsername, "m_sptbClientLogin_GetUserByUserMobile"); //call webservices it return String , loginDetailsArray = loginDetails.split(",");

Comment: Yes, but *what's actually in the string* when you call split on it? Debug it, print it out, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace @ or any special characters with equivalent sign;

However you may not change password charactres.

Your SMS API might be not allowing passing Special characters.

Answer (score -1):

You does not encode character '@'. Encode it ->
**@amp;**

Comment: Are you getting confused with `&`, which you'd need replace with the entity  `&amp;`? The `@` symbol doesn't need encoding in XML, and if it did, that probably wouldn't be the way to do it.